# Translation parameters for menu items using KnpMenuBundle and Symfony3

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, knpmenubundle, knpmenu

### Introduction

In my personal project I am using:

- XAMPP with PHP `v7.1.6`
- Symfony `v3.3.6`
- KnpMnenuBundle `dev-master / 2.2.x-dev` [[link 1]](https://packagist.org/packages/knplabs/knp-menu#dev-master), [[link 2]](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/KnpMenuBundle/index.html), [[link 3]](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle) in order to manage Menus.
- Bootstrap `v3.3.7`
- Bootstrap and KnpMenuBundle integration [[link 4]](https://gist.github.com/Invis1ble/503db8bb9ff6dafc52c8b2bf7c6fec42)

### Setting up

To setup i used documentation in [2], [3] and code samples [4]. My menu is working, integration between `Bootstrap` and `KnpMenuBundle` also works.

### At the moment

Menu bundle works fine, *simple* translating works and integration works too.

My `ProfileMenu` code sample:

```
public function profileMenu(array $options)
{
    $menu = $this->factory->createItem('root');
    $menu->setChildrenAttribute('class', 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right');

    $menu->addChild('Profile', array('label' => 'menu.profile'))
        ->setExtras(array('dropdown' => true, 'icon' => 'fa fa-user'))
        ->setLinkAttribute('class', "dropdown-toggle")
        ->setLinkAttribute('data-toggle', "dropdown")
        ->setExtra('translation_domain', 'menu');

    $menu['Profile']->setChildrenAttribute("class", "dropdown-menu")
        ->addChild('Logged in as', array('label' => 'layout.logged_in_as'))
        ->setExtra('divider_append', true)
        ->setExtra('translation_domain', 'FOSUserBundle');

    $menu['Profile']->setChildrenAttribute("class", "dropdown-menu")
        ->addChild('My data', array('label' => 'menu.profile.myData', 'route' => 'fos_user_profile_show'))
        ->setExtra('translation_domain', 'menu');
    $menu['Profile']->setChildrenAttribute("class", "dropdown-menu")
        ->addChild('Edit data', array('label' => 'menu.profile.editMyData', 'route' => 'fos_user_profile_edit'))
        ->setExtra('translation_domain', 'menu');
    $menu['Profile']->setChildrenAttribute("class", "dropdown-menu")
        ->addChild('Change password', array('label' => 'menu.profile.changePassword', 'route' => 'fos_user_change_password'))
        ->setExtra('translation_domain', 'menu');

    $menu['Profile']->setChildrenAttribute("class", "dropdown-menu")
        ->addChild('Exit', array('label' => 'menu.profile.logout', 'route' => 'fos_user_security_logout'))
        ->setExtra('divider_prepend', true)
        ->setExtra('translation_domain', 'menu');

    return $menu;
}
```

menu rendering is shown in following image

[image: menu rendering]

### Question

How can i pass translation parameters (namely `%username%`) to menu (powered by KnpMenuBundle) and get it to render as intended?

How can one supply arguments:

```
|trans({'%username%': app.user.username}
```

in the `MenuBuilder`?

### MY CODE

The code block in question is

```
$menu['Profile']->setChildrenAttribute("class", "dropdown-menu")
    ->addChild('Logged in as', array('label' => 'layout.logged_in_as'))
    ->setExtra('divider_append', true)
    ->setExtra('translation_domain', 'FOSUserBundle');
```

namely `label` string

Translating strings with parameters ordinarily, one would supply arguments like so:

```
<li><a href="#">{{ 'layout.logged_in_as'|trans({'%username%': app.user.username}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}</a></li>
```

Yet, i can not seem to figure out how to pass them in case of using `KnpMenuBundle` and `Bootstrap` integration.

### Conclusion

Please advise.

Thank you for your time and knowledge.

Comment: I have a follow up question https://stackoverflow.com/q/46007289/3137047

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could declare your MenuBuilder as a service like this

```
#services.yml
app.menu_builder:
        class: AppBundle\Menu\MenuBuilder
        arguments:
            - @knp_menu.factory
            - @security.token_storage
            - @translator.default
```

Update `MenuBuilder`'s constructor according to the dependencies on the above definition

With this you have access to all the things you need to perform your traduction

```
$user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser(); // If you are under a path protect by security.yml access_constrol
$yourLoggedInTraduction = $this->translator->trans(
    'layout.logged_in_as', [
        '%username%' => $user->getUsername()
    ], 
    'FOSUserBundle', 
    'yourlocale'
); 
dump($yourLoggedInTraduction);
```

You should have your traduction and then map it to your `profileMenu(...)` function logic

**I don't use sames version of symfony/knpMenu than you so maybe this code won't work directly but you just have to adapt to your needs**

Ask for question if you want if it isn't clear

I hope I have helped you, if yes please mark the post as resolved !  : )

Answer (score 1):

A specific option `extras.translation_params` is available but not documented: 
https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle/blob/master/src/Resources/views/menu.html.twig#L7

You can use it in the same way you used the `translation_domain` option:

```php
$menu['Profile']->setChildrenAttribute("class", "dropdown-menu")
    ->addChild('Logged in as', array('label' => 'layout.logged_in_as'))
    ->setExtra('divider_append', true)
    ->setExtra('translation_domain', 'FOSUserBundle')
    ->setExtra('translation_params', ['%username%' => $user->getUsername()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Simple answer to your question

Simply translate the label passed to `addChild`:

```
$label = $this->translator->trans('layout.logged_in_as', ['%user%' => $username ]);
$menu->addChild('Logged in as', array('label' => $label);
```

`$this->translator` is a `\Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface` that is injected into the service creating the menu. I got it by passing `"@translator"` as an argument to the constructor in `services.yml`.

## Add multiple child menus

For the sake of completeness, I'll also note that every child menu must have a different name. So, if you want to create multiple menus with different parameters, make sure you don't copy/paste the first line without also changing the menu name.

Or use something like this:

```
$idx = 0;
$menu->addChild("Language_".$idx++, array('label' => $label_lang1);
$menu->addChild("Language_".$idx++, array('label' => $label_lang2);
```

Or, if all the child menus are generated in one file:

```
$menu->addChild("Language_".__LINE__, array('label' => $label_lang1);
$menu->addChild("Language_".__LINE__, array('label' => $label_lang2);
```

If you don't use different names, only the last menu is displayed.

## Avoid missing translation warnings

With the above solution, the symfony toolbar and the log both report warnings about missing messages. That's because the provided label can't be found in the translation domain (in `messages.yml` or whatever you use for your translations).

To avoid those false positive, add the following line after the `addChild` call:

```
$menu->addChild('Logged in as', array('label' => $label)
     ->setExtra('translation_domain', false);
```