# How to exclude certain string from showing up in missing translations using KnpMenuBundle and Symfony3

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, knpmenubundle, knpmenu

### Introduction

In my personal project I am using:

- XAMPP with PHP `v7.1.6`
- Symfony `v3.3.8`
- KnpMnenuBundle `dev-master / 2.2.x-dev` (`dev` version because it is compatible with current `Symfony 3.3.x` version, earlier versions did not install via `composer`.) [[link 1]](https://packagist.org/packages/knplabs/knp-menu#dev-master), [[link 2]](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/KnpMenuBundle/index.html), [[link 3]](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle) in order to manage Menus.
- Bootstrap `v3.3.7`
- Bootstrap and KnpMenuBundle integration [[link 4]](https://gist.github.com/Invis1ble/503db8bb9ff6dafc52c8b2bf7c6fec42)

### Setting up

To setup i used documentation in [2], [3] and code samples [4]. My menu is working, integration between `Bootstrap` and `KnpMenuBundle` also works.

### Problem

I am using `Logged in as myTestUserName` in `user profile` part of the menu. And i would like to exclude this item from translation as i am getting full translated string manually (code example 1).

At the moment even with `translation_domain` explicitly set to `false` i get said menu item in the  missing section of `Translation Messages` section in the `profiler`.

### Images

[image]

[image]

### Question

What is the correct way of making sure specific translations are not included in missing section in case of using `KnpMenuBundle`?

### CODE: sample 1

sample of my `MenuBuilder`

```
$profile->setChildrenAttribute("class", "dropdown-menu")
    ->addChild('Logged in as', array('label' => $getTranslatedLoggedInAs))
    ->setExtra('divider_append', true)
    ->setExtra('translation_domain', false);
```

### CODE: sample 2

getting `loggedInAs` translated string in `MenuBuilder`

```
public function getTranslatedLoggedInAs()
{
    $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
    //dump($user);

    $translated_logged_in_as = '';

    $anonymous_user = 'anon.';
    if ($user->getUsername() !== $anonymous_user)
    {
        $translated_logged_in_as = $this->translator->trans(
            'layout.logged_in_as', ['%username%' => $user->getUsername()], 'FOSUserBundle'
        );
    }
    elseif ($user->getUsername() === $anonymous_user)
    {
        $translated_logged_in_as = $this->translator->trans(
            'layout.logged_in_as', ['%username%' => $anonymous_user], 'FOSUserBundle'
        );
    }

    return $translated_logged_in_as;
}
```

### Conclusion

Please advise.

Thank you for your time and knowledge.

Comment: do you use bundle templates or custom templates to show menu?

Comment: I am using custom template (as seen in [link 4]) that overrides `KnpMenuBundle` default template in order to use `Bootstrap` integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you have error in [link 4] in block `label`. `translation_domain` is not checked for `false` and label is translated in any way.

```
{% block label %}{{ item.label|trans(
    item.getExtra('translation_params', {}),
    item.getExtra('translation_domain')
) }}{% endblock %}
```

Look how it works in `KnpMenuBundle` https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle/blob/master/Resources/views/menu.html.twig

```
{% block label %}
    {%- set translation_domain = item.extra('translation_domain', 'messages') -%}
    {%- set label = item.label -%}
    {%- if translation_domain is not same as(false) -%}
        {%- set label = label|trans(item.extra('translation_params', {}), translation_domain) -%}
    {%- endif -%}
    {%- if options.allow_safe_labels and item.extra('safe_label', false) %}{{ label|raw }}{% else %}{{ label }}{% endif -%}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thank you @Max P. your answer is 100% correct. I copied original `label block` to the overriding template and now have no missing translations.